# How do you make a picture pop out of a div of elements (CLOSED)

Tags: html, css

I made a flexed div that contains my name, ID and picture:

```css
.version2 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.version2 div {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    align-self: center;
}

#propic{
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyHeader</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="version2">
        <div><strong>Name:</strong> Tahmin Ahmed </div>
        <div><strong>ID:</strong> 123456</div>
        <picture>
            <img id="propic" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/av1Fi.png" alt="My Profile picture">
        </picture>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the blue background to be only **slightly** larger than the text and the picture to *overflow out of the blue background downwards*. What do I have to add/remove to achieve this?
[This is what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGduP.png)

Comment: Can you create your willing result with something like paint so I can understand what you exactly want?

Comment: how about using `transform: translateY(100px)` to your image?

Comment: Or **minus bottom margin**?

Comment: Apparently I had to set a fixed height of sorts to my parent div to get the desired effect. Thank you for the alternative options tho 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the desired effect you are looking for?  I just added a fixed height to your outer `.version2` container:

```css
.version2 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 2rem; /* added a fixed height */
}

.version2 div {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    align-self: center;
}

#propic{
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyHeader</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="version2">
        <div><strong>Name:</strong> Tahmin Ahmed </div>
        <div><strong>ID:</strong> 123456</div>
        <picture>
            <img id="propic" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/av1Fi.png" alt="My Profile picture">
        </picture>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you!